# How would I getElementById from a Rails View

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails view with the following HTML:

```
<tbody>
  <% @requests.each do |request| %>
     <tr data-request-id="<%= request.id %>">
       <td id="artist" style="text-align: center"><%= request.artist %></td>
       <td style="text-align: center"><%= request.title %></td>
       <td style="text-align: center" class="voteCount"><%= request.voteCount %></td>
       <td style="text-align: center"><%= button_to 'Vote', request_upvote_path(request.id), remote: true, method: :post, onclick: 'upVote()', class: 'upVote' %></td>
     </tr>
   <% end %>
</tbody>
```

I'm trying to access the voteCount cell in the table, but I'm not sure how to do it. Normally in JS I would use `document.GetElementById` or `GetElementBysClassName`

I have a method that increments the `voteCount` number by 1 when the button is clicked, which works fine, but this JS function needs to increment the correct request.

Here's the current JS:

```
function upVote() {
   var count = document.getElementsByClassName("voteCount")[0].innerHTML;
   count = parseInt(count);
   count = count + 1;
   count = count.toString();
   document.getElementsByClassName("voteCount")[0].innerHTML = count;
   document.getElementsByClassName("upVote")[0].disabled = "true";
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the JS needs to send the result to the server so that it stays the same on page refresh?

Comment: Initially I just want it to update the html, but eventually I do want it to save to the database as well. Im trying to take it one step at a time, but if I can get to that point first Im all for it.

Comment: I see, so is the JS part working? If not, what exactly is your issue?

Comment: The JS is not working currently. The problem is that I have a button that increments a value on the page, but I don't know how to get the ID of the correct button. So, the current code will always increment the first index in the array, but I need it to increment according to the corresponding index. In other words, if I click the vote button on the 3rd item on the page, it increments the first. i need it to increment the 3rd. My current code of `getElementsByClassName` doesn't work because it's not dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. You can pass the id onclick with rails and the just use the regular `getElementById` in JavaScript:

```
<tbody>
  <% @requests.each do |request| %>
 <tr data-request-id="<%= request.id %>">
   <td id="artist" style="text-align: center"><%= request.artist %></td>
   <td style="text-align: center"><%= request.title %></td>
   <td style="text-align: center" id="voteCount<%= request.id %>"><%= request.voteCount %></td>
   <td style="text-align: center"><%= button_to 'Vote', request_upvote_path(request.id), remote: true, method: :post, onclick: "upVote(#{request.id})", class: 'upVote', id:"voteButton#{request.id}" %></td>
 </tr>
   <% end %>


function upVote(id) {
   var count = document.getElementById("voteCount" + id).innerHTML;
   count = parseInt(count);
   count = count + 1;
   count = count.toString();
   document.getElementById("voteCount" + id).innerHTML = count;
   document.getElementById("voteButton" + id).disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good idea, but when I try to pass `<%= request.id %>` as an argument to the JS method, Im getting a syntax error

Comment: `index.html.erb:25: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end ...;@output_buffer.safe_append=')\', class: \'upvote\' %></td> ... ^ `

Comment: Ok that works in incrementing the votes, which is awesome. The other piece, the disabling of the button after the click, doesnt look like it's working though. I edited the cell to be:  `<td style="text-align: center" id="voteButton<%= request.id %>"><%= button_to 'Vote', request_upvote_path(request.id), remote: true, method: :post, onclick: "upVote(#{request.id})", class: 'upVote' %></td>`

Comment: You are passing a string to disabled. It should be a boolean. Remove the quotes and it should work.

Comment: It was actually working the way I had it, using the string, just not the right element because of the same issue. I updated it to a boolean `document.getElementById("voteButton" + id).disabled = true;` but that didnt work

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thanks so much!